# Finding missing number in an unsorted array

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

> You are given an unsorted array of all the integers in the range $0$
>   to $n = 2^k -1$ except for one integer, called the missing number.
>   Find a divide and conquer algorithm to find the missing number in time
>   $O(n)$. If you wish, you may use the fact that an algorithm
>   $median(A)$ exists that can find the median of an array $A$ of $n$
>   numbers in time $O(n)$. The median of $n=2m$ numbers is the average of
>   the $m$th smallest and $m$th largest number.

I am not sure where to start any hint would be much appreciated. The solution without Divide and Conquer would be to find the sum of the array and subtract it from the computed sum $n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to use divide and conquer here. You can just run down the list and keep a checklist for all of the $2^k$ numbers, then find the missing entry. The list contains $2^k$ entries, so this takes $O(2^k)$ steps But since $n=2^k-1$ this is also $O(n)$.
You can do the same thing in divide and conquer fashion if you so choose, but that amounts to just checking all the numbers in a different order. You're not saving any time doing that.

Answer (score -1):

An efficient way to do this kind of thing without using unusually precise knowledge of the contents of the array is to sort the array and then make
a single pass to find the gap.